# Non comprehensible result from PowerBi measure

Tags: powerbi, calculation, measure

While writing my diploma I have run into some problems with the measure function of PowerBi. First of all, my measure:

```
VAR __CATEGORY_VALUES = VALUES('UD_PT'[UD_PT_VALUE])
VAR __BEFRAGTEN_CNT = VALUES('UMFRAGEDATEN'[UD_BEFRAGTENANZAHL])
VAR __HUNNAT = 100
RETURN
        DIVIDE(
            __BEFRAGTEN_CNT * 
            DIVIDE(
            __CATEGORY_VALUES;
            __HUNNAT
            );
            __BEFRAGTEN_CNT
        )
```

In my data-warehouse is data from surveys about politics and votes.

- __CATEGORY_VALUES: This is a number between 1 and 100. It represents the amount of votes a specific party got during ONE specific survey in percent. (Basically the number of votes divided by the amount of questioned people times 100) UD_PT is a table containing values of these numbers and a view other things. It has a foreign key to the table 'UMFRAGEDATEN' which contains things like the total amount of questioned people during a specific survey and another foreign key to the table 'PARTEI' in which are all partys.
- __BEFRAGTEN_CNT: In here is the amount of all questioned people (For ONE specific survey as well)

(Example: 
__CATEGORY_VALUES: 20
__BEFRAGTEN_CNT : 1000
So during this survey a total of 1000 people were questioned. 20% of which voted for a specific Party)

My goal here is to get the amount of people that voted for ONE specific party during this ONE specific survey. In the example above the result should be 50. Somehow, though, it will not visualize the measure because it seems to return a table of values when it only should return one.

The exception I get is as follows (Roughly translated):
The data for the visualisation was not found.
MdxScript(Model)(31,13) Calcualtion error in measure'UD_PT'[Measure]: A table with multiple values was returned, even though, a single value was expected

Im looking forward to help since I've been scratching my head for a view hours now and Google didn't provide the answer I was looking for.

EDIT: The visualisation I'm trying to produce is a line diagramm. X-Axis are years (2015-2020) On the Y-Axis there should be a view lines (each line representing a party). The value in the Y-Axis should be the amount of votes a party got, in relation to the amount of people questioned during a survey. Since in my data set are different surveys, some of which not containing some of the partys I also need to group these values for each year, ignoring missing data and only showing the top 5 partys with the most votes.

The solution doesn't have to involve measures. You can solve it however you like (with an R-Script for example) but I'd apreciate it if you could explain how you did what.

Here a representation of out database:
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIOR9.png)

Comment: Could you please add your data model diagram picture that shows tables and their relations?

Comment: Sorry, that took a while but I added it now.